Select cursor define position

Hello, how can I set the cursor position to retrieve the number in the wheel segments?
<div class="wheel-container">
            <div class="spinBtn">Tourner</div>
            <div class="wheel">
                <span style="--i:0;"></span>
                <span style="--i:1;"></span>
                <span style="--i:2;"></span>
                <span style="--i:3;"></span>
                <span style="--i:4;"></span>
                <span style="--i:5;"></span>
                <span style="--i:6;"></span>
                <span style="--i:7;"></span>
                <span style="--i:8;"></span>
                <span style="--i:9;"></span>
                <span style="--i:10;"></span>
                <span style="--i:11;"></span>
                <span style="--i:12;"></span>
                <span style="--i:13;"></span>
                <span style="--i:14;"></span>
                <span style="--i:15;"></span>
                <span style="--i:16;"></span>
                <span style="--i:17;"></span>
                <span style="--i:18;"></span>
                <span style="--i:19;"></span>
                <span style="--i:20;"></span>
                <span style="--i:21;"></span>
                <span style="--i:22;"></span>
                <span style="--i:23;"></span>
                <span style="--i:24;"></span>
                <span style="--i:25;"></span>
                <span style="--i:26;"></span>
                <span style="--i:27;"></span>
                <span style="--i:28;"></span>
                <span style="--i:29;"></span>
                <span style="--i:30;"></span>
                <span style="--i:31;"></span>
                <span style="--i:32;"></span>
                <span style="--i:33;"></span>
                <span style="--i:34;"></span>
                <span style="--i:35;"></span>
                <span style="--i:36;"></span>
                <span style="--i:37;"></span>
                <span style="--i:38;"></span>
                <span style="--i:39;"></span>
                <span style="--i:40;"></span>
                <span style="--i:41;"></span>
                <span style="--i:42;"></span>
                <span style="--i:43;"></span>
                <span style="--i:44;"></span>
                <span style="--i:45;"></span>
                <span style="--i:46;"></span>
                <span style="--i:47;"></span>
                <span style="--i:48;"></span>
                <span style="--i:49;"></span>
                <span style="--i:50;"></span>
                <span style="--i:51;"></span>
                <span style="--i:52;"></span>
                <span style="--i:53;"></span>
                <span style="--i:54;"></span>
                <span style="--i:55;"></span>
                <span style="--i:56;"></span>
                <span style="--i:57;"></span>
                <span style="--i:58;"></span>
                <span style="--i:59;"></span>
                <span style="--i:60;"></span>
                <span style="--i:61;"></span>
                <div class="number">
                    <b id="0" style="--i:0;">0</b>
                    <b id="1" style="--i:1;">1</b>
                    <b id="2" style="--i:2;">2</b>
                    <b id="3" style="--i:3;">3</b>
                    <b id="4" style="--i:4;">4</b>
                    <b id="5" style="--i:5;">5</b>
                    <b id="6" style="--i:6;">6</b>
                    <b id="7" style="--i:7;">7</b>
                    <b id="8" style="--i:8;">8</b>
                    <b id="9" style="--i:9;">9</b>
                    <b id="10" style="--i:10;">10</b>
                    <b id="11" style="--i:11;">11</b>
                    <b id="12" style="--i:12;">12</b>
                    <b id="13" style="--i:13;">13</b>
                    <b id="14" style="--i:14;">14</b>
                    <b id="15" style="--i:15;">15</b>
                    <b id="16" style="--i:16;">16</b>
                    <b id="17" style="--i:17;">17</b>
                    <b id="18" style="--i:18;">18</b>
                    <b id="19" style="--i:19;">19</b>
                    <b id="20" style="--i:20;">20</b>
                    <b id="21" style="--i:21;">21</b>
                    <b id="22" style="--i:22;">22</b>
                    <b id="23" style="--i:23;">23</b>
                    <b id="24" style="--i:24;">24</b>
                    <b id="25" style="--i:25;">25</b>
                    <b id="26" style="--i:26;">26</b>
                    <b id="27" style="--i:27;">27</b>
                    <b id="28" style="--i:28;">28</b>
                    <b id="29" style="--i:29;">29</b>
                    <b id="30" style="--i:30;">30</b>
                    <b id="31" style="--i:31;">31</b>
                    <b id="32" style="--i:32;">32</b>
                    <b id="33" style="--i:33;">33</b>
                    <b id="34" style="--i:34;">34</b>
                    <b id="35" style="--i:35;">35</b>
                    <b id="36" style="--i:36;">36</b>
                    <b id="37" style="--i:37;">37</b>
                    <b id="38" style="--i:38;">38</b>
                    <b id="39" style="--i:39;">39</b>
                    <b id="40" style="--i:40;">40</b>
                    <b id="41" style="--i:41;">41</b>
                    <b id="42" style="--i:42;">42</b>
                    <b id="43" style="--i:43;">43</b>
                    <b id="44" style="--i:44;">44</b>
                    <b id="45" style="--i:45;">45</b>
                    <b id="46" style="--i:46;">46</b>
                    <b id="47" style="--i:47;">47</b>
                    <b id="48" style="--i:48;">48</b>
                    <b id="49" style="--i:49;">49</b>
                    <b id="50" style="--i:50;">50</b>
                    <b id="51" style="--i:51;">51</b>
                    <b id="52" style="--i:52;">52</b>
                    <b id="53" style="--i:53;">53</b>
                    <b id="54" style="--i:54;">54</b>
                    <b id="55" style="--i:55;">55</b>
                    <b id="56" style="--i:56;">56</b>
                    <b id="57" style="--i:57;">57</b>
                    <b id="58" style="--i:58;">58</b>
                    <b id="59" style="--i:59;">59</b>
                    <b id="60" style="--i:60;">60</b>
                    <b id="61" style="--i:61;">61</b>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

Can you help me do this?
I tried to retrieve the id of the b tags to do it but I can't do it
I created this code like this to set the number of segments of the wheel with

span

tags and display the numbers in the segments with

b

tags
@justnut:
This is a part of my js code i use for turn this wheel
    const spinDuration = 3600; // Durée de la rotation en secondes
let wheel = document.querySelector('.wheel');
let spinBtn = document.querySelector('.spinBtn');
let value = Math.ceil(Math.random() * -3600);
spinBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const spanIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length); // Obtenir un index aléatoire
    wheel.style.transform = `rotate(${value}deg)`;
    value += Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3600);

I add my css code too :
.wheel-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.wheel-container::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -90px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 100000;
    clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 35% 50%, 65% 50%);
}
.wheel {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 5px solid #FF69B4;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #c9357f;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: transform 5s ease-in-out;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wheel span {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 1px);
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #FF69B4;
    transform: rotate(calc(360deg / 62 * var(--i)));
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px #FF69B4);
}
.spinBtn {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 200px;
    background-color: #FF69B4;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 10000;
    cursor: pointer;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px #FF69B4);
    user-select: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
}
.number {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    rotate: 20.15deg;
}
.number b {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 10px;
    transform: rotate(calc(360deg / 62 * var(--i)));
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 500;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px #FF69B4);
}


Is there more missing, how are you handling making the wheel spin. I would say your best bet would be using the angle of the segments to see which would be at the top but not completely sure with what you’ve provided :)

@justnut i have edit my first post with a part of my js code

You cannot achieve that according to my knowledge. If your goal is to show random number on wheelspin then what you can do is pick a random number using Math.random() in js & then use border , background color or anything else to highlight that number on wheelspin by targeting ID. Explanation is too short and confusing maybe but if you want to consider this option then I will post detailed one.

For calculating the segment you land on, I believe it will depend on what you start on but you will need to do some calculations like the following.
Math.floor((value%360) / (360/numberofsegments))

This should give you the index of which the segment it lands on. May have to adjust a bit so log it and adjust it a bit by however off it is.
You also can use for loops to generate those span elements so you don’t have to manually do all of that.
